# «Утверждения британского мининдел Джонсона»

Tags: неологизмы

Зачем это недорасшифрованное, одновременно и не только МИД, но и главного дипломата страны обозначающее слово? Каковы его шансы на перспективу?

Информация запоздавшая, но нужная: слово — совсем не популярное — может дожить тихой сапой до своего столетия в 2026 г. Взлёт его отмечен НКРЯ в 1933-м, а обвал — сразу после ВОВ.

Comment: Откуда это (источник известен)?

Comment: Из сегодняшней статьи  Исраэля Шамира на https://mediametrics.ru/rating/ru/online.html

Comment: Статья не там, а на сайте Новороссия: https://novorossia.su/news/padayushchego-tolkni

Comment: По второму разу найти не мог, — улетела новость.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в словаре:

Мининдел
Министерство иностранных дел

([Словарь сокращений русского языка](https://abbr_rus.academic.ru/12582/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB))

> Мининдел — МИД Мининдел министерство иностранных дел гос. МИД Словарь: С. Фадеев. Словарь сокращений современного русского языка. С. Пб.: Политехника, 1997. 527 с.

А вот с [сайта МИД России](http://www.mid.ru/foreign_policy/news/-/asset_publisher/cKNonkJE02Bw/content/id/2836674)

> Встреча с мининдел Боливии.

и еще 658 вхождений.

Похоже, про министра — проф. жаргон.

Comment: И похоже, в значении "министра" это слово повсеместно не склоняется и не изменяется по числу (когда таких собирают от разных стран). Наркоминдел (министр, с маленькой) - склонялся, существуя в единственном числе (если единовременно).

Comment: @Alex_ander  Да, вот пример с того же сайта МИД: "...встреча мининдел России, Турции и Ирана..."